# OIM - Assign organization to entitlement in Java code

Tags: organization, entitlements, oim

How can I assign organization to entitlement in Java code?

On the user interface I can assign organizations to the entitlement.

Regards,
Attila

I tried to assign get and update entitlement.

```
EntitlementService _entservice = (EntitlementService)Platform.getService(EntitlementService.class);
Entitlement ent = _entservice.findEntitlement(entitlementkey.longValue());
...
_entservice.updateEntitlement(ent);
```